# How to calculate height of camera and ground coverage via geometry?

Tags: geometry

I have a GoPro7 that I will mount on a pickup vehicle to capture ground images with video capture.

The camera isn't top down but has about 20 (or 30) degrees inclination from the vertical axis.
I want to capture the road that is 4m in width.

Other givens would be:

- Vertical Field of View: 71.0deg
- Horizontal FoV: 86.7deg
- Diagonal FoV: 100deg
- Sensor size: 1/2.3” (6.17×4.55mm)
- Aperture: f/2.8
- Zoom: 0%
- Frame width: 4:3

I would like to know if it is possible (and how) to calculate the needed height of the GoPro for this.

Comment: I think this is off-topic here. You'd probably be better off asking here https://photo.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ThePointer i think it is a mathematical question tho

Comment: No, it isn't. Just because your question involves calculations does not make it a mathematics question. As I said, I think you're looking for photo.stackexchange – not math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correct you want to mount your camera $x$ meters above the road where
$$
x = \frac{L}{2} \tan\bigl(\frac{\alpha\pi}{180}\bigr)\cos\bigl(\frac{\beta\pi}{180}\bigr)
$$
and where
$$
\begin{align*}
L &= \text{width of road} = 4~\text{m}\\
\alpha &= 90-\tfrac12(\text{Horizontal FoV})=90 - \tfrac12 86.70 = 46.65^\circ\\
\beta &= \text{inclination from the vertical axis} = \text{20–30}^\circ
\end{align*}
$$

For $\beta=20^\circ$ you get $1.99087$ m and for $\beta=30^\circ$ you get $1.8348$ m.

Explanation:

Consider front view of the camera

[image]

The road is of width $L$ and $\alpha=\text{Horizontal FoV}$. The (sloping) distance from the camera to the road is $x$.

We have
$$
\tan(\alpha/2)=\frac{L/2}{x}
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
x=\frac{L}{2\tan(\alpha/2)}.
$$

Now, consider the camera from the side (looking at the car from the side);

[image]

where $\beta=\text{inclination from the vertical axis}$ and $x$ the sloping line above. We want to find $h$.

We have
$$
\cos(\beta)=\frac{h}{x}
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
h=x\cos(\beta).
$$

Hence
$$
h=\frac{L}{2\tan(\alpha/2)}\cos(\beta).
$$

This is a variant of the formula above as
$$
\tan(90^\circ-\alpha/2)=\cot(\alpha/2)=\frac{1}{\tan(\alpha/2)}.
$$

Perhaps US readers prefer
$$
h=\frac{L}{2}\cot(\alpha/2)\cos(\beta).
$$

N.B.1: ‘inclination’ might be $90^\circ-\beta$ depending on definition, but if so it easy to find the $\beta$ used in the calculation by $\beta=90^\circ-\text{inclination}$.

N.B.2: The calculations above assumes that the calculator is set to *degrees*. If the calculator is set to *radians* the formula becomes
$$
h
=\frac{L}{2\tan(\alpha\pi/360)}\cos(\beta\pi/180)
=\frac{L}{2}\cot(\alpha\pi/360)\cos(\beta\pi/180).
$$

Comment: thanks for this. I would just like to ask how it was derived and why does it only use Horizontal FoV?

Comment: I assumed you had the camera in landscape orientation. Then the horisontal FoV decides how much of the road is captured. I can make a sketch and upload a bit later today.

Comment: @bluewander Added calculations

Comment: Can I ask where did you find 90degrees?

Comment: whre did 90degrees came from and why are the cos and cot different from the original/first formula?

Comment: The first formula assumes calculator set to radians and angle given in degree. The second formula assumes calculator set to degrees so no conversion needed. I usually have the calculator always set to radians though. I updated the text at the end.